# $http get to a Rails ApplicationController gives "HTTP Error 406 Not acceptable" against angular 1.1+ build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, angularjs

If you are calling a Rails service like this:

```
 $http.get(url).success(successFn)
               .error(
                      function(data, status, headers, config) {
                               console.log('Failed');
                      }
                     );
```

And your Rails ApplicationController responds like this:

```
   def your_service

      # do some stuff

      respond_to do |format|
         format.js { render 'shared/common_js' }
      end
   end
```

Using angular 1.0.x everything goes on smoothly and your service answers OK 200.

Then I tried the same code against the unstable 1.1.x build and things stopped working with a HTTP Error 406 Not acceptable.

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: The problem is that for me has been quite difficult to find out the solution so I just wanted to point it out, so that others can google it.

Comment: Well, this is not the right place for that. Please look at the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  . You can either post it to your blog or post the question and then answer it on your own and accept it.

Comment: Tahnks Nishant, I will reformat the question asap.
The point is that to me stackoverflow is a really valuable resource (I start here and if I cannot find anything relevant I start googling the web), so I think it's better to have it here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Guess I have to wait for some hours to give my answer: 

"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours."

Comment: 1.1.x is still unstable. If you found a bug, create an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues)

Comment: Thaks asgoth. Well, I think it's more like a "known" issue... People at angular discussed about it: it has to do with easiness of CORS requests. I got to wait some hours, then I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I spent a few hours investigating this, hopefully this will save someone else's time.

After a debug session, finally I spotted that the difference was in the request headers:

```
1.0.3 (at this time):  {X-Requested-With: "XMLHttpRequest", Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", X-XSRF-TOKEN: undefined} 

1.1.1 (at this time):  {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", X-XSRF-TOKEN: undefined}
```

So I googled for "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest removed" and I finally spotted out this commit:

($http): remove 'X-Requested-With' from header defaults
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d

(This removal was the result of some discussions, and is basically meant to allow smoother CORS requests)

With this removal, Rails can no more find is way through the service, that is:

```
format.js { render 'shared/common_js' }
```

gets no more triggered (actually format.html is)!

A possible fix is:

```
    $http( {method: 'GET', url: url , headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'}})
           .success(successFn)
           .error(
                           function(data, status, headers, config) {
                               console.log('Fail');
                             }
                         );
```

Otherwise, as stated in the commit, you can bring back the missing headers like this:

```
myAppModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

Hope this helpful, cheers.

Comment: Thank.. This saved me much time.. I wonder why they removed them from defaults. I don't quite understand...

Comment: Thank you so much for putting the hours into finding this solution so I didn't have to. Worked out of the box.

Comment: This is the only solution that's worked for me. I have the exact same problem as described in the question. I'm using Angular 1.2.18 and Rails 4.0.2.

Comment: Thanks for your supportive comments. 
I am regaining some confidence: sorry if it sounds a little "flamy" but if it were for some moderator I would never have posted the question in the first place... Anyway I appreciate. Thx

Comment: Still a mistery to me, altough this is fit for a quick fix, thanks.